# Why the upload progress become 0%?

Tags: iphone, background, progress

My program needs to upload some data to the server and I use percentage to show the progress in a `UIAlertView`. When the program starts uploading, for example, the progress is 10%. I put the program into background and it continued uploading. When I pulled the program back to foreground after ten seconds, the percentage in the `UIAlertView` became 0% for seconds and then turned to normal, such as 40%. I don't know why this happen, can anyone help me please?

Comment: You should post some code to show how you are setting the progress.

Answer (score 1):

It could be that when your appcomes to foreground, perhaps your alertview progress is being set to 0 (initial value) before it updates correctly to the updated progress value.

Comment: +1, you can update it manually in `viewWillAppear`/`viewDidAppear`